# Trigonometric vs Synthetic solutions for olympiad geometry problem...

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In a triangle $ABC$ $\angle ABC=40^\circ$ , pick a point $D$ inside the triangle such that $\angle DCB=\angle ABD=\angle DBC=20^\circ$ and $|AB|=|AD|$, what is $\angle DCA=\alpha$

**My Synthetic Solution**
If we take The symmetric of point $B$ as $B'$ and complete $B'$ to $C$ we have an equilateral triangle, from here $60-\alpha=50^\circ$ and $\alpha=10^\circ$....

My question is how do we get a trigonometric solution from here?[image]

Comment: I'm getting $ADC$ angle to be $200°$

Comment: Hi, I've added The picture of the question in case İ misrepresented some parts of it

Comment: Would you please explain, why getting the answer is not enough?

Comment: I didn't mean anything bad, I already knew that the answer was $10^\circ$ not because I solved it myself, because it was formally posted, and I thought you might have found it that way due to my misrepresentation. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle ACD=x$ and $AB=a$.

Thus,$\measuredangle ADC=140^{\circ}$, $\measuredangle DAC=40^{\circ}-x$ and by the law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{\sin(40^{\circ}-x)}{\sin{x}}=\frac{DC}{AD}=\frac{a}{2a\sin{x}}=\frac{1}{2\sin10^{\circ}}.$$
Thus, $$\sin40^{\circ}\cot{x}-\cos40^{\circ}=\frac{1}{2\sin10^{\circ}},$$ which gives
$$\cot{x}=\frac{1+2\sin10^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ}}{2\sin10^{\circ}\sin40^{\circ}}$$
and since
$$\frac{1+2\sin10^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ}}{2\sin10^{\circ}\sin40^{\circ}}=\frac{1+\sin50^{\circ}-\sin30^{\circ}}{2\sin10^{\circ}\sin40^{\circ}}=\frac{\sin50^{\circ}+\sin30^{\circ}}{2\sin10^{\circ}\sin40^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{2\sin40^{\circ}\cos10^{\circ}}{2\sin10^{\circ}\sin40^{\circ}}=\cot10^{\circ},$$
we obtain $$x=10^{\circ}$$
and we are done!

Comment: Hello, I've added a picture to the body, in case I misrepresented the question.

Comment: @Deniz Tuna Yalçın I fixed my post. See now.

Comment: @Deniz Tuna Yalçın You are welcome!